# Must I add a noun after "in retaliation for"? Can I add a gerund?

Tags: american-english, gerunds, prepositional-phrases

My own example:

> I kicked in his ass in retaliation for his bullying/he bullying me few days ago.

Comment: Do you mean "I kicked him in the ass..."? I'm not sure that "kicked in his ass" is physically possible. Alternately, "I kicked his ass".

Comment: "For he bullying me" is not correct.  Either "his" or "him".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking here, because a gerund *is* a noun. But yes, it's typical to use a gerund in this context, because it's a noun that describes an action, and you are taking an action in retaliation.

The grammar in your example isn't quite right, thought (the gerund itself is fine but there's a few other issues:

- The idiomatic phrase you're looking for is *kicked his ass*. If you say you kicked someone *in the ass*, assuming that you didn't mean it literally, it usually means something like "motivated him to work harder". The phrase *kicked his ass* means to assault, beat-up, or otherwise injure, which I think you want.
- The prepositional phrase after *in retaliaton* isn't a sentance, so you don't want to use the subject pronoun *he*, you want to use either *him* or *his*. You can also typically omit the pronoun completely, since it's implied that "he" is the one that did whatever you are retaliating for.

Any of the following would express the idea you want:

> I kicked his ass in retaliation for him bullying me few days ago.
>
> I kicked his ass in retaliation for his bullying of me a few days ago.
>
> I kicked his ass in retaliation for bullying me a few days ago.

Of course, you don't *need* to use a gerund here, you could use any noun that made sense, e.g.:

> I kicked his ass in retaliation for his actions a few days ago.